# 3 pixel stroke on headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wanting to apply a 3px stroke to my header text in order to keep it in line with the design of the rest of my site. I'd also prefer to not use images for this for two reasons: maintainability and overhead.

I'm aware I can use the `text-stroke` property however it doesn't seem to have wide browser support: http://caniuse.com/text-stroke

The other method I'm aware of is using `text-shadow` like this:

```
text-shadow: -3px -3px 0 #d3d3d3, 3px -3px 0 #d3d3d3, -3px 3px 0 #d3d3d3, 3px 3px 0 #d3d3d3;
```

However, that method doesn't result in a solid line around the glyphs, as you can see in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdcwy/

Is there a single, reliable way to add a decent looking 3px stroke around text with little overhead? I don't mind using a JavaScript/jQuery library but I'd rather not use images.

Comment: Assuming you got that from this page http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/, it says `The primary issue is that you can only get 1px of stroke this way. Any more, and you see gaps.`.

Comment: I know, hence my question.

Comment: Then take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760789/text-stroke-and-shadow-css3-in-firefox `The text-stroke property isn't part of the standard CSS spec, so it's best to avoid it - Chrome would be well within their rights to pull out it at any time.`

Comment: When you say you want to keep it in line with the rest of your site, does that mean you have stroked text elsewhere?

Comment: can you use svg?? http://jsfiddle.net/mdcwy/41/

Comment: @ultranaut Yeah, the logo has a 3px stroke and the top navigation bar has a 3px border-bottom, no part of the site has text with a 3px border yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JS to generate your `text-shadow`:

```
var el = document.getElementById('foo'),
    shadow = '',
    width = 10,
    color = '#d3d3d3';
for(var i=-width; i<=width; ++i) {
    shadow += ', '+i+'px '+width+'px 0 '+color
        + ', '+i+'px '+-width+'px 0 '+color
        + ', '+width+'px '+i+'px 0 '+color
        + ', '+-width+'px '+i+'px 0 '+color;
}
el.style.textShadow = shadow.substring(2);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mdcwy/39/)

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of offsetting the shadow as you go around and using a few more steps.

```
text-shadow: -1px -3px 0 #d3d3d3, 1px -3px 0 #d3d3d3, 
             -1px 3px 0 #d3d3d3, 1px 3px 0 #d3d3d3, 
             -3px -1px 0 #d3d3d3, 3px -1px 0 #d3d3d3,
             -3px 1px 0 #d3d3d3, 3px 1px 0 #d3d3d3, 
             -3px -3px 0 #d3d3d3, 3px -3px 0 #d3d3d3, 
             -3px 3px 0 #d3d3d3, 3px 3px 0 #d3d3d3;
```

[jsfiddle.net/mdcwy/35/](http://jsfiddle.net/mdcwy/35/)